# Extra space on right of website in android webview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn java and thought building an app for a website I frequent would help me learn. However, I get a white bar on the right that I can scroll over to. If I block horizontal scrolling it doesn't help because when I go from portrait to landscape and back again, it ends up in my view.

Is there anything I can do in my code to fix this? The website is frontpagelinux.com and here is the most basic code I can create that shows it:

```
    package com.frontpagelinux;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WebView mywebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mywebView.loadUrl("https://frontpagelinux.com/");
           
            mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you own that site? If not, it'll generally be an uphill battle in terms of accounting for design quirks. If you still want to "fix" it, you can play around with the CSS by injecting javascript into the site. Something like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-element').forEach(el => el.style.width = '100vw')
```

And then in your Android code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WebView mywebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mywebView.loadUrl("https://frontpagelinux.com/");
            mywebView.evaluateJavascript("your js fix here");
           
            mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't own the site. I just thought it'd be a good learning project to take a website that's interesting to me and make an app for it. Apparently, I picked a site that requires more learning than I initially thought.

Would I put that document.querySelectorAll inside the evaluateJavascript expression? If so, I'll try that out and see if it works. It will give me something to start with, at least.